# react js compilation is successful but no output

Tags: reactjs, web, tailwind-css, mern

build successful but no output here is the git repo link https://github.com/ganu123/my-project
I am new in react js please help

Comment: Hi @Ganesh.
which command you're using?npm start or npm run build?

Comment: i am using npm start / npm run start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw the repo and found you didn't wrap your app with Router as you're using Routes

index.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
<BrowserRouter>
    <App />
</BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

reportWebVitals();
```

App.js

```js
import './App.css';
import {Route} from "react-router-dom";
// HOC
import DefaultHOC from './HOC/Default.HOC.js';
import {  Switch } from "react-router-dom";
// Component
import Temp from './components/temp';

function App() {
  return (
    <Switch>
    <DefaultHOC path="/" exact component= {Temp}/>
    </Switch>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thank you now it's working

Comment: Sounds great.
it would be really helpful if you upvote and accept by clicking tick mark this answer if it helped you
Thanks

Comment: I don't have permission to upvote but I accepted it